# How to setup a network connection between an android phone and the web browser on pc using a wifi network?

Tags: android, networking, tcp, connection, android-camera2

Is it possible to connect my Android phone (Redmi Note 7) directly to my Windows (10) PC in such a way that I can make network connections to the PC from the phone, with/without a per-existing WiFi network?

My specific issue is that I want to be able to connect the camera of my android phone with the web browser using a specific IP address. This IP address when typed on the browser would open a screen that would help us to connect with the android device, basically feeding in everything what the android device camera sees.

I've already done my work on the camera2API interface work, I just need some help with the network connection part.

Ideally I'd like a solution that doesn't involve the Internet at all - neither from the PC nor the phone. In my particular situation, it would also be ideal if this can be done over a WiFi network connected via a single IP(same for phone and to be typed on the browser) would suffice.

I really need help with developing an android app that would help me to setup the connection between the android phone and PC using the TCP/IP protocol. There is already an app for serving such a purpose whose link I am providing below, but I have to add some security and login features on the existing app. All i am asking is how would I set up such a connection in the first place and proceed forward with the app.Also, Bluetooth provides a very less upload speed, and about the USB, i am trying to make the total process wireless. the link to the existing app: ip-webcam.appspot.com

Comment: Please post a code snippet you tried so far. So is not a code writing service. You should post code along with the question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am working at a similar app, and I use a modified web server for configuration and delivering images (I am doing it on the native side though, but I am sure there are plenty of Java web servers out there).